# How remove the space in matrix?

Tags: math-mode

Why the space? how remove the space?

[image]

```
\begin{gather}
 W =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    {1^W}^T\\
    {2^W}^T \\
  . &\\
  . &\\
   {s^W}^T
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
```

Comment: Get rid of the two `&` tabs, which create a second column.

Comment: although it isn't mentioned in the question, the dots don't look too good.  (this was questioned in a comment to the accepted answer.)  this problem is addressed in answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286701/579

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get rid of the two `&` tab separators...they result in the creation of a 2nd column in the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
 W =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    {1^W}^T\\
    {2^W}^T \\
  . \\
  . \\
   {s^W}^T
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, consider replacing the `.\\.\\` with `\vdots\\`, as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
 W =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    {1^W}^T\\
    {2^W}^T \\
  \vdots \\
   {s^W}^T
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is there more space between `{2^W}^T` and `\vdots`?

Comment: @manooooh -- `\vdots` is constructed from periods, which sit on the baseline, so there's quite a lot of "air" above the top one.  some methods for compacting them or adjusting the vertical space appear in answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412407/579 .

Comment: @barbarabeeton excellent! It is something similar with `\[\begin{cases}...\end{cases} \equiv \begin{cases}...\end{cases}\]`, right?

Comment: @manooooh it is similar if you wish the syntax of `cases` (left brace, no right brace).  Another differrence, `bmatrix` uses center alignment, where as `cases` uses right/left, right/left alignment.