# Excess vertical space in \vdots

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-spacing

How do I get a tight `\fbox` around `\vdots`? There is an excess vertical space as discussed in

- [Vertical space around \vdots in xymatrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412407/4301)
- [Wrong (too much) vertical space above \vdots in small matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207056/430)

The code below produces:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Defined in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412418/4301
\newcommand{\myvdots}{\raisebox{.006\baselineskip}{\ensuremath{\vdots}}}

\begin{document}
p
\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\vdots}
\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\myvdots}
y
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `\vdots` expands to a `\vbox`, so the `\ensuremath` is rather useless.

Comment: This question deals with the spacing in `\vdots`: [Mathematical optimization problem doesn't look good](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286701)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The definition of `\vdots` in `fontmath.ltx` reads

```
\DeclareRobustCommand
  \vdots{\vbox{\baselineskip4\p@ \lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern6\p@\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}
```

(This is inherited  from `plain.tex` with the addition of robustness.)
I don't quite know the idea behind the `\kern6\p@` bit, but removing it removes the excess box height

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand
  \myvdots{\vbox{\baselineskip4\p@ \lineskiplimit\z@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt
p \fbox{\vdots} \fbox{\myvdots} y

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `\baselineskip` is set to 4pt, the total height will be 14pt plus the height of the period. It is an example of an *ad hoc* macro by Knuth that was blindly copied to LaTeX.

Comment: @egrer A-ha. I was just adding that the macro is in fact inherited by plain `:-)`