# Properly creating a boxed vertical vector of math symbols in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath

I am trying to create a boxed vertical vector of math symbols in TikZ. My goal is to have all the terms centered in the box (vertically and horizontally) and have the box auto-sized to fit around everything with the desired `sep`. I was able to achieve this using a `minipage` combined with a `gather*` environment, but it seems hacky since I have to manually remove some extra space at the top and set the `minipage` width. I'm wondering if there is a "proper" or more elegant way of achieving this result.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=1mm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black,fill=white,rounded corners,ultra thick,inner sep=2.5mm] (u) {  
    \begin{minipage}{8mm}
        \centering
        \vspace{-5mm}
        \begin{gather*} 
            u^0 \\ 
            u^1 \\ 
            \vdots \\ 
            u^{N-1} 
        \end{gather*}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{-5mm}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The space above `\vdots` is, sadly, built in, and not originating with `amsmath`.  Take a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528774

Comment: @barbarabeeton If that's the case for `\vdots`, then I will accept that, but I'm manually editing the space above `u^0` and the width of the box. I'm not sure if this can be done without a `minipage`, but it would be simpler if that wasn't required.

Comment: I was only addressing the `\vdots` spacing -- that's inherited from plain TeX.  @David has taken care of the centering and overall dimensions; both he and I have worked on the `amsmath` user documentation over the years, so I'm glad you find it understandable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All AMS alignments have a `...ed` form that is set natural width rather than being a full width display, so you can avoid `minipage` with `gathered`

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=1mm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black,fill=white,rounded corners,ultra thick,inner sep=2.5mm] (u) {%  
       $\begin{gathered} 
            u^0 \\ 
            u^1 \\[-.7em] 
            \vdots \\ 
            u^{N-1} 
        \end{gathered}$%
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I prefer your solution over Sandy's since it doesn't require going in and out of math mode (everything is in one `gathered` environment). I haven't heard about the `...ed` amsmath alignment forms. Do you have a link that explains the differences and when one might want to use one over the other?

Comment: `texdoc amsldoc` will bring up the doc but there are no cases where you could use either. `align`, `gather`, ... are like `equation`: display environments that you start from a paragraph and they make a full width math display. `aligned`, `gathered`, ... are like `array` they are a natural width alignments that makes a term within an existing math formula. @jared

Comment: The example in "3.7 Alignment building blocks" clarifies things nicely for me.

Comment: I suppose I should scold you for using `em` as a vertical dimension.  (Yes, I know the nominal default font is square, but not all are.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton you should never scold me

Comment: @barbarabeeton What should be used instead of `em`? I'm using this in a beamer presentation with a sans-serif font, so it might be relevant.

Comment: @jared barbara is suggesting I use 1ex rather than .7em although it doesn't make a lot of difference here really, both are just chosen "by eye" to look about right and the both change with the current font size, which is the important part.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for `minipage` or `gather` or `centering`. Just add `align=center` to your node options and you can use multiline contents with `\\`. Optional vertical spacing can be added.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black, fill=white, rounded corners, ultra thick, inner sep=2.5mm, align=center] (u) {  
            $u^0$ \\ 
            $u^1$ \\ 
            $\vdots$ \\[.8ex]
            $u^{N-1}$ 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's certainly a lot simpler. Is the `[0.8ex]` somehow dealing with the extra space above `\vdots` or is it doing something else?

Comment: Note this uses tighter superscript spacing most noticable in the last row where the bottom of the N is well below the top of the u, this may be good or bad depending on what the OP wants:-) (+1 either way:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't notice that, but it seems insignificant that it does not matter for my use case. Is it tighter because it's not using `displaystyle`?

Comment: @jared yes exactly

Comment: @jared: The `[.8ex]` adds vertical space after the `\vdots`. As David Carlisle correctly notes, the spacing here is tighter than yours so I thought adding space below looked better than removing space above.